# How to get value from MVC controller action on page asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a page with cascad downloaded areas (select something in first area -> downloaded specific data to second area).

And I need to hide some content depending on data from the first area.

I need something like this (in javascript):

```
var result = getDataFromController(controllerName:"Quotes", 
                                   actionName:"IsQuoteOrdered",
                                   param: quoteId);
```

Comment: "I need something like this" that's a strong affirmation, so... are we your employees? how about "Can anyone assist me" or a simple "What should be the path to take"... no?

Comment: You're not my employee, so no one is force you to answer if you don't like statement of the question. I asked direct question and I think different "oh please help me" / "balexander, please look at me from your throne. you're only one who can help me" is only a "noice" which is distracts from main theme of a question. IMHO, of course :) don;t take it to hard next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using jquery to simplify the ajax calls.

If you go that route the following would allow you to replace the dd2 element portion of the page with the result of a controller action call upon change of selection in dd1 :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dd1').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: 'firstDropdownSelectedValue=' + $('#dd1').val(),
            url: 'YourControllerName/YourActionName',
            success: function (data) {
              $('#dynamicDivPortionOfThePageReturnedByYourView').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I need to perform call to controller not on onload of page but e.g. on button click. I copied just $.ajax(..) call and it didn't work :(

Comment: I've tried once again and it **worked**. probably browser cached js